# Продолжить переход на event.target после сабмита модального окна

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. После любых изменений на вкладке и переходе в другое место вывожу запрос на подтверждение перехода без сохранения.

```
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e){ 
           if (vIsChange)
           {
               e.preventDefault();
               $('#modal_title').text('Есть не сохраненные данные!');
               $('#ModalLabel').text('Перейти без сохранения изменений?');
               $("#modal_form").attr('action', "window.location = "+ e.target );**//видимо что-то тут не так.** 
               $('#newModal').modal('toggle');
           }
           else
               window.location = e.target;
       });
```

Как правильно продолжить переход после подтверждения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решил вопрос таким образом.
При переключении табов

```
   $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e){
       if (vIsChange == true)
       {
        if ( !confirm("Есть не сохраненные данные! Перейти без сохранения изменений?")) {
            e.preventDefault();

        }
        else {
            vIsChange = false;
        }
       }

   });
```

При переходе на другую страничку.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
               if ( vIsChange )
                   return true;
           };
```

Правда это уже не кастомный модал. Но мне пока и такое пойдет.